# Button to open new page and auto fill some form elements

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I sell a tremendous number of products that require finance of one kind or another. I also use 8 different lending sources for financing. Problem is that each lender works with certain product types and ages, etc. I can not use a generic application form due to the differences in each lenders requirements. I have added <kbd>APPLY NOW</kbd> Button(s) to each individual product but cannot use simple "goto" link.

Example(s):
Customer 1 views product ID#20, unit is 20 years old and only one particular lender will work.
Customer 2 views product ID#55, unit is brand new and all will work with it, but I send all       new products to one lender in particular.

<kbd>Apply Now</kbd> Button is always the same image, but I need for the button to open the application page specific to that product, and auto fill the input fields such as Vendor Name, Product Name and Description, Price, Etc as most customers are unfortunately lazy and simply won't do that once they have been taken away from the product page. I figure I will need to code the button individually based on individual products to open the correct application, but want all to fill in the information. All items for AutoFill are stored in the Store Database as well as the Vendor (Store) Info.

Maybe I am in the wrong area or simply missed the answer somewhere else, but I am getting snow blind trying to find the answers...even a point in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to link the product with a lender type, this would make it easier to grab lander data and auto populate the form fields when the page loads. This way you would not need to change the "Apply Now" link.

In short I would suggest creating a link table between product/product type to the lender table.